# How to check if multiple string variables aren't null or empty?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to check some string variables if they are null or empty here is the code which i wrote but i know its with problems :

```
if (!(empty($classid)&&(empty($dayid))&&(empty($academicyearid))&&(empty($semesterid)))) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The strings are empty');</script>";}
```

I will get the input of those strings from a database with the mysqli_fetch_array function.
The problem is that i tried a simple example which indicates why the code above doesnt work .This is the simple expample that i tried:

```
<?php
$d='';$x='1';
if (1<3){
        if (!(empty($x)&&(empty($d)))){

        echo "esjte null";
        die();
        }
}
echo "it didnt work";

?>
```

eventhough one of them is empty i mean the $d variable it will echo the string "ejste null" how can i fix it so it will check if both the variables aren't empty and not just only one. 
Thx.

Comment: FYI - Checking using !trim($myVar)... should also work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed exclamation mark after && this checks if both are not empty, if you want to check if either one is not empty replace && (and) with || (or) operators

```
<?php
$d='';$x='1';
if (1<3){
    if (!empty($x) && !empty($d)){
    echo "esjte null";
    die();
    }
}
echo "it didnt work";
?>
```

Examples with operators:

```
 if (!empty($x) && !empty($d)) // if BOTH are not empty
 if (!empty($x) || !empty($d)) // if AT LEAST ONE is not empty
```

Comment: It didnt work i just tried i got the "esjte null" echo again but i shouldnt get it cause $d is empty

Comment: Sory your are right it worked but i missed something in the code thx

Answer (score 0):

is_null is a function finds whether a variable is NULL. You can refer this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Answer (score 0):

**empty(var)** returns true if a variable is empty, but you are using **!empty(var)**, which returns false.

So when you test an empty value, your test is not passing.

```
// AND test if both are empty == true
if(empty($x) && empty($y)) 

// OR test at least one is empty == true
if(empty($x) || empty($y))
```

The exclamation mark reverse the result of your test.

```
// if BOTH are empty this returns false and you test fails
if (!empty($x) && !empty($d))
```

Comment: Infact that is what i wanted to check if they arent empty but the answer of Tomas Liutvinas seems to work.Your answers makes sense to. I could use a if{}else{} statement and it would work to thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (empty($classid) && empty($dayid) && empty($academicyearid) && empty($semesterid)) 
{echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The strings are empty');</script>";}
```